PWM to control 12V DC fan not working
When using the PWM to control the fan, the fan only turns on when reaching 12V DC.
If I hook up power supply direct the fan will turn on at 5V DC.
What am I missing?




"What am I missing?" The datasheet link for the controller and the fan. (Please [edit] them into your question - not the comments.) Note that your fan doesn't have a simple brushed DC motor. There is a miniature three-phase motor in there with a driver chip to convert from DC to AC. It may not work with a pulse-width-modulated (PWM) supply voltage if that's what your controller is giving it. Welcome to EE.SE.

I’m sure this has been detailed before, but you cannot control a BLDC fan that self commutates with a PWM controller because the fan includes a bulk e-cap across the leads which is incompatible with PWM switched voltage.
Use an active or passive resistance to control the speed in an analog mode. Choose the minimum speed to be about 40% of V+ to avoid stalled blades then FET heat spreading to the internal e-cap.
You could use an NFET or carefully designed BJT driver on the Blk -ve lead to draw current  but at 2.5V out the fan rated power will be equal to the NPN but now at 50% of rated. Thus a heat sink is needed.
Alternatively use a variable DCDC supply from 2 to 5V or use a thermistor to control the fan voltage according to some temperature set point.

Hey thanks for your info. Variable DCDC supply isn't going to happen, 12V from the jeep is what I have to work with. That leaves active or passive resistance to control. Can you expand  on this? Remember you are dealing with someone that doesn't know much about this. I want to keep it small as it will be installed inline on the wiring going to the fans. Thanks James

Sure. The commutation for the BLDC inside the fan makes the load look like a fixed R when constant speed. Say a fan is 12V * 0.25A = 3W , then R load looks like 12V/0.25 = 48 Ohms so inserting a 2Watt 50 Ohm R will half the voltage to the fan at half the current or 1/4 power and speed reduces to slow. Intermediate values like 22 Ohms will draw more volts and supply 2/3 power and more RPM to the fan and less heat dissipation from R. If the resistor was 1.5W it would operate at 150'C thus oversized runs cooler.

You could use a couple of transistors rated with 5W heatsink  and a Pot to control variable speed but this is more fancy and needs more details.  If you have a 50W fan then you need  25W resistor at 25% power half voltage using R= W/14V^2 for the g=fan R equiv.

Doh. I see you have two 6W fans, @ 14.2V it's 8.2W each & runs too fast/ hot maybe for the motor. So another way is to convert the PWM to a filtered DC.
2x 6W fans @12V = 12 Ohms  Convert the PWM to a filtered DC
Choose series L= 330 uH 0.1 Ohms digikey.ca/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/2218-V-RC/775415 and parallel polarized Polymer cap. = 150 uF 35V rated for  3A @ 100kHz +ve to output of the L choke and bar side (-ve) to ground.  Cap https://tinyurl.com/54jnhtd9     Filter simulation https://tinyurl.com/2dc9qe9y
